# Energy eigen value for a perturbed free particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

Suppose we have a one-dimensional free particle system and we introduce a perturbation like $V(x)=V_{0} \cos(Gx)$, where $G$ is the reciprocal lattice vector (it's a periodic perturbation, I think)

Now, how can we calculate the energy eigen-value spectrum $E_{n}$?

I think the equation is of the form: $(H-E_{n})\psi_{n}=0$ where $H=H_{0}+ V_{0}cos(2 \pi /a)$ and the wave function are the free particle one: $e^{ikx}$

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave. The problem is, that the solutions, I believe, use the Mathieu functions, which are not very commonly taught except in fields where periodic perturbations are common, e.g. in astronomy to solve periodic perturbations of planetary orbits. The Kronig–Penney model gets you the same physics, but with far less mathematical heartbreak, I believe.

Comment: can't we solve it through perturbation?

Comment: I suppose so, the question is, whether an arbitrarily small perturbation acting over an arbitrarily long time or large spatial domain results in a small effect. I don't think it does, in this case. The splitting will probably occur at any strength of the potential and your solution must deal with that.